# Error statement is not logged, only *password---- with many dashes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use extended events to store database errors, like this:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [ErrorCapture] 
ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported
(
    ACTION
    (
        sqlserver.client_hostname,
        sqlserver.database_id,
        sqlserver.sql_text,
        sqlserver.username
    )
    WHERE 
    (
        [severity] >= (11)
    )
) 
ADD TARGET package0.asynchronous_file_target
(
    SET filename='J:\ServerXmlOutput\ErrorCapture.xel'
)
WITH 
(
    MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,
    EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,
    MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=10 SECONDS,
    MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,
    MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,
    TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,
    STARTUP_STATE=ON
);
```

This works great.
Sometimes, the SQL statement (sql_text) that is logged contains only the following:

```
*password------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What is the reason, and how do I find out which statement is causing this?

Comment: The same issue happens also for SQL Trace, when some procedure has a parameter called [@password]. The events are cleared out for obfuscation purposes (even if the pwd value is encrypted) so Profiler (or XE) isn't used for unintended purposes. Not very familiar with XE so don't know how to advise you further. Maybe check if you have a procedure with parameter [@password] and change it (for tests only) to a different name? Or a table with a column Password?

Comment: That could be an answer. Is there any way to disable this behaviour?

Comment: Sure, don't have parameters like @password.

Comment: I now don't have any procedure with parameter @password, still the errors like that keep coming.
May this also be caused by a database column named "password" or "abc_password"  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is confirmed that this is caused by a column called `password` or an argument `@password`.

A column called `abc_password` does not cause this behaviour.

Comment: You should mark your answer as the answer.